# The proposition about the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence and  $a_k \geqq 0$ for all $k$.

Proposition;

\begin{equation}
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k< \infty \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k=0 \quad \cdots \ast
\end{equation}

I know the fact that if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges, $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=0$ and I thought that I could use this fact for the proof of $\ast$.
But I couldn't prove.

I want you to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Try unfolding the definition of limit and of convergent series and then connect the two with a common choice of $N$.

The following is a complete proof.

> Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, $S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $b_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k$. We wish to prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n = 0$. Set an $\epsilon > 0$ and choose a natural number $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|S_n - S| < \epsilon$. Note that $S = S_n + b_{n+1}$ and therefore, for all $n \geq N$, $|b_{n+1}| = |S_n - S| < \epsilon$ as required.

**Edit**: As a follow-up, you may want to prove that a sequence converges iff any of its tails converge. You can find solutions here: [A sequence converges iff the tail converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961684/a-sequence-converges-iff-the-tail-converges). These are simple consequences of the definition of convergence, understanding their proofs will better your understanding of the definition.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $ n\ge 2$.

For $ m $ great enough,

$$S(n,m)=\sum_{k=1}^ma_k$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+\sum_{k=n}^ma_k$$

Put $ L=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_k$

then

$$\lim_{m\to+\infty}S(n,m)=L$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+\lim_{m\to+\infty}\sum_n^ma_k$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+\sum_n^{+\infty}a_k=L$$

Now, make $ n$ going to infinity.